# Search Form on JQuery Dialog

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

Im wondering if anyone could clue me in as to how to set up a search form in a Jquery Dialog. I want this to work through AJAX. I had tried using something like this:

```
<%= form_tag teachers_path, :method => 'get', :remote=> 'true' do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

Then on my controller:

```
def index
    @teachers= Teacher.search(params[:search])
end
```

And model:

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
  else
    find(:all)
  end
end
```

Now, when i hit the "submit" button, since it's got a "remote" attribute, it wont force the page to reload, but then the search thing doesnt happen either. I know im missing something, or probably im on the wrong track, so a hand is much appreciated here.

I tried my best to look for suitable answers to this questions, but ultimately couldnt find anything.

Comment: Is the search action being fired off in the controller and the return value simply not being parsed, or is the submit button actually not doing anything?

Comment: Submit button is firing the action, i believe. I checked the CMD and the server seems to be passing the param "search" with the value i insert in the text field, but then it doesnt filter the data and dont give me anything.

Comment: I was thinking, is there a way to pass a string as a param and then use that param in a SQL query to find all rows that contain the given string in any of its columns?

Like if for example there's 2 registry in my table that have "John" and "Johnny" in the "name" field, and i pass the string "john" as a param, and then use it in a select query so that it searches in my table all registries that contain the string "John", would it bring me back both "John" and "Johnny" registries?

Comment: I assume this is hard to do since noone's been able to provide an answer :( Im desperate..!

Comment: Ok, i had somehow figured this out. My search is working within my dialog. I will post the answer to my own question once i set everything right. :)

Answer (score 0):

After several hours of research and testing, I had managed to make what I intended. Below I will post what I did.

Controller

```
def index
    @teachers= Teacher.search(params[:search])
end
```

Model

```
 def self.search(search)
        if search
            case $search_by
                when '1'
                    find(:all, :conditions => ['name ILIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
                when '2'
                    find(:all, :conditions => ['address ILIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
            end
        else
            find(:all)
        end
    end
```

Index

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><b><%= label_tag "Teacher:" %></td>
    <td><%= text_field_tag(:teacher," " ,:id => "teacher", :size => 3,     :onchange=>"selection('typed_teacher', this)")%>
    <span id="filtros"><%= image_tag "SearchIcon2.png",   :onclick=>"selection('search_teacher', this)", :height =>'20', :width => '20', :title=>"Search", :valign=>"middle", :class=>"pin_image" %></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The image tag is the one that calls up the dialog. The "selection" function is described below. Basically what it does is bringing up the teacher's information (name, address, phone, ID) and paints it on the screen (the data displaying will be omitted for this example since its irrelevant to the code), what I need is the "id" of the teacher. I'd typed in the text_field (if I know the teacher's id) or search for it on the dialog, which is what I was trying to accomplish.

Selection Function

```
function selection(pmodel,elObj) 
    {
        var dataString = 'model='+pmodel+'&search='+code+';  
        document.getElementById('mydivdialog').innerHTML=" ";
        $.ajax(
        {  
        type: "GET",  
        url: "/teachers/show",  
        data: dataString  
        }); 

        return false;
    };
```

That calls the "show.js.erb" file that i have on my folder. Next i explain what's in there (only the dialog related part).

Show.js.erb

```
$( "#midivdialog" ).dialog(
                {
                    modal: true,
                    height: 400,
                    width: 550,
                    stack: true,
                    buttons: 
                        {
                    Cancel: function() 
                      {
                         $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                      }
                   }
                }
            );
$(document.getElementById("mydivdialog").innerHTML= " ");
$("<%= escape_javascript(render "list") %>").appendTo("#mydivdialog");
$("<%= escape_javascript(render "teachers") %>").appendTo("#theteachers");
```

The "list" partial is where I will be doing the search, here's what goes there:

```
<%= form_tag(@teachers, :method=> "get", :id=> "searching", :remote=> true) do %>
    <b>Search By: </b>  
    <fieldset class = "ui-widget-content ui-corner-all", style = "width: 420px;  padding: 0px;">
        <%= radio_button_tag :search_by, '1' %> Name| <%= radio_button_tag :buscar_por, '2' %> Address
    </fieldset>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :form=> "searching", :name => nil %>
<% end %>   

<div id= "the_teachers"></div>
```

Here's the "teachers" partial that will be rendered whenever the "search" button is submitted:

```
<font size="2">
    <% @buscar = params[:search] %>
    <% @bancas = Banca.search(@buscar) %>                        
    <table class = "tabla">
        <tbody> 
            <tr class = "ui-widget-header">
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Phone Number</th>
            <% @bancas.each do |det| %>
               <tr onclick="takeGeneric('<%= det.teacher_id %>','<%= det.name %>','<%= det.address %>','<%= det.phone %>')">
                        <td><%= det.teacher_id %></td>
                        <td><%= det.name %></td>
                        <td><%= det.address %></td>
                        <td><%= det.phone %></td>
                    </tr>
                <% end %>
            <% end %>
        <tbody>
    </table>
</font>
```

The following code goes in the "teachers" partial, it what handles the onclick event. This is not related to the dialog, but thought I'd add it in case someone'd need it.

```
<script>
    function takeGeneric(paramcod, paramname, paramaddress, paramphone)
      { 
      $( "#teacher" ).val(paramcod);
      $("#teacherdata").replaceWith('<div id="teacherdata"><table><thead><tr><td style = "width: 250px">'+paramname+'</td></tr> <tr><td>'+paramaddress+'</td></tr> <tr><td>'+paramphone+'</td></tr></thead></table></div>');
      $(document.getElementById('teacherdata').style.fontSize = "13px");

       $( "#mydivdialog" ).dialog( "close" );   
      };

</script>
```

Ok, that's it. It should be working (it is for me).